# Graphics glitch in the transparent regions of a ImageView rotated with CGAffineTransformRotate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

Im writing an application for the iPad and I have a strange graphics problem.

I have a UIImageView, with transparent regions, that is being rotated using CGAffineTransformRotate.

My problem is that a lot of the graphics behind the image view (in the transparent regions) is repainted and appears to move very slightly from side to side, creating a very noticeable and annoying glitch. It only occurs in the transparent regions and everything outside of the rotated image view is looking still.

Anyone know what might be causing this bug? And is there a way to fix it? (I could maybe convert the entire thing to Open GL, but that would be a big work around...)

Comment: Screenshots, please. That shouldn’t happen.

Comment: Here is a video displaying the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eeaIA74rn2g&feature=youtu.be  ,I turn on blended layers in the debug and also turn off the rotation in the end.